# wcf configuration questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm still new to WCF and had a few questions on why certain sections are needed, if they are, in WCF:

1) I have a application which uses a WCF service to talk to the database.  I setup a test SSL certificate on my local machine and setup the web.config of the WCF service as:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Since I have SSL setup I read I had to have Transport security, by setting the clientCredentialType to Windows what does that do?  Isn't SSL taking care of the security of data being passed back and forth?  The message piece I get, because I setup a custom class to authenticate the user.  I just don't understand why I need it for Transport, if I don't need it, what does it do when it's setup to Windows, does that mean that all messages within a company network are fine, but if anything outside that network tries to talk to the service it's blocked?

2) For this section:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

when i go to production, both should be set to false correct? So this way any other application which tries to setup a Service Reference to the production url will be blocked, or not be able to build the proxy classes?

3) includeExceptionDetailInFaults, should i always leave that as false?  Currently when an error occurs in the WCF Service, i'm have the code throw a new FaultException, which then propagates up to the method in the web application, which is sending me an email with the error message, users just get a generic error page.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.If you are using your service internally, then you can use this config, but
   Both client and server should be on same domain. 
   Windows Credentials are required because certain Certificates are placed at User Level Certificate store in Windows, to authenticate them, you need to provide user credentials.

2.If you don't want any one to create proxy, then go ahead.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

Indicates, that the user can see the WSDL metadata only on https connection and not on http. So if some needs to create proxy, they have to use the https url of your service.

3.Depends on your requirement, If you don't want your user to see the error details. then it's OK. This is required only for debugging. So you are right.

[More details on Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700.aspx)

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

Answer (score 1):

Much useful info here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354508.aspx

and here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx

1) Transport Security is just handling the Network-level security; when you specify Message+Transport, you're saying you want the message itself to require authentication as well; just having a valid SSL config isn't enough.  ClientCredential Windows, means to attempt to use the effective windows credential of the running process.

> By default, the wsHttpBinding binding provides HTTP communication. When configured for transport security, the binding supports HTTPS communication. HTTPS provides confidentiality and integrity protection for the messages that are transmitted over the wire. However the set of authentication mechanisms that can be used to authenticate the client to the service is limited to what the HTTPS transport supports. Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) offers a TransportWithMessageCredential security mode that is designed to overcome this limitation. When this security mode is configured, the transport security is used to provide confidentiality and integrity for the transmitted messages and to perform the service authentication. However, the client authentication is performed by putting the client credential directly in the message. This allows you to use any credential type that is supported by the message security mode for the client authentication while keeping the performance benefit of transport security mode.

2) Whether or not you allow HTTP "GET" operations is entirely up to you and your security preferences; it does obscure your service a bit, but makes it less easy to use.

3) Whether you include exception details in your response depends largely on how much you trust the consumers of your service.  When consumers have the exception they'll be better able to react to their own mistakes, but also have more information about your service's implementation.